# Class vs. function template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates, template-classes

I only recently learned about partial template specialization in C++ from [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/13-8-partial-template-specialization-for-pointers/), and it perfectly solved a problem where I needed a template class to behave differently for pointers and non-pointers. A simplified example is:

```
// main.cpp

template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
  C( const T& t ) : t_( t ) {}
private:
  T t_;
};

template <typename T>
class C<T*>
{
public:
  C( const T& t ) : t_( new T(t) ) {}
  ~C() { delete t_; }
private:
  T* t_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  C<int>  c1(4);
  C<int*> c2(2);

  return 0;
}
```

I wanted to try extend this idea to functions, but ran into compiler errors I didn't understand:

```
// main.cpp
#include <set>

template <typename T>
std::set<T> makeSet( size_t off )
{
  std::set<T> s;
  s.insert( T() + T(off) );
  return s;
}

template <typename T>
std::set<T*> makeSet<T*>( size_t off )
{
  std::set<T*> s;
  T* t = new T( T() + T(off) );
  s.insert( t );
  return s;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::set<int>  s1 = makeSet<int>(4);
  std::set<int*> s2 = makeSet<int*>(2);

  delete *(s2.begin());

  return 0;
}
```

.

```
$ g++ --version && g++ -g ./main.cpp
g++ (GCC) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.cpp:13:38: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘makeSet<T*>’ is not allowed
   13 | std::set<T*> makeSet<T*>( size_t off )
      |                                      ^
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./main.cpp:23:37: error: call of overloaded ‘makeSet<int>(int)’ is ambiguous
   23 |   std::set<int>  s1 = makeSet<int>(4);
      |                                     ^
./main.cpp:5:13: note: candidate: ‘std::set<T> makeSet(size_t) [with T = int; size_t = long unsigned int]’
    5 | std::set<T> makeSet( size_t off )
      |             ^~~~~~~
./main.cpp:13:14: note: candidate: ‘std::set<T*> makeSet(size_t) [with T = int; size_t = long unsigned int]’
   13 | std::set<T*> makeSet<T*>( size_t off )
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~
./main.cpp:24:38: error: call of overloaded ‘makeSet<int*>(int)’ is ambiguous
   24 |   std::set<int*> s2 = makeSet<int*>(2);
      |                                      ^
./main.cpp:5:13: note: candidate: ‘std::set<T> makeSet(size_t) [with T = int*; size_t = long unsigned int]’
    5 | std::set<T> makeSet( size_t off )
      |             ^~~~~~~
./main.cpp:13:14: note: candidate: ‘std::set<T*> makeSet(size_t) [with T = int*; size_t = long unsigned int]’
   13 | std::set<T*> makeSet<T*>( size_t off )
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

I was a little skeptical about this because it looks like an attempt at overloading a function with a different return-type but with the same arguments - I know this is otherwise illegal, but I thought that because these were template functions, specifying the template type when invoking the functions (as in the above `main()`) would allow disambiguation.

But I'm not sure that's what the compiler is complaining about on line 13: **what does the `non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘makeSet<T*>’ is not allowed` error mean?**

**Is what I'm trying to do even possible in C++? I.e. can a template function be made so that it behaves differently for pointers and non-pointer template types and return a STL container of the specified type?** (Would the answer be different between C++ 98, 03, 11, and 14?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what does the `non-class, non-variable partial specialization ‘makeSet<T*>’ is not allowed` error mean?

Let's take a look at some documentation [from cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) regarding partial template specialization:

> Allows customizing class [and variable (since C++14)] templates for a given category of template arguments.

Partial specializations are allowed for class and variable templates. The compiler has told you that your template is for neither a class for a variable. Therefore, partial specialization is not allowed.

A less confusing wording for the compiler's message would be: partial specialization of function templates is not allowed.

---

As for what can be done, it is possible to declare a class template with a suitable `operator()`. In some cases this is about as good as using a function template.

Comment: Nice suggestion RE: the `operator()` - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (C++17):

```
template <typename T>
std::set<T> makeSet( size_t off )
{
  std::set<T> s;
  if constexpr(std::is_pointer_v<T>)
  {
    using U = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>;
    s.insert(new U( U() + U(off) ));
  }
  else
  {
    s.insert( T() + T(off) );
  }
  return s;
}
```